# how to delete / update record from my text file in ( C )

Tags: c, linked-list

i have a text file and store records in this in c language. i insert and select is good work fine. but delete and update not work :

my select code is work fine :

```
void SQLselect(const struct TokenList *list, const struct TableStructureInfo *const     tableStructure)
{
struct Table table;

if (tableStructure == NULL)
    return;
table = SQLloadTable(list, tableStructure);

SQLprintTable(&table);
 }
```

i write delete function this but not work :

```
 void SQLdelete(struct TokenList *list, const struct TableStructureInfo *const tableStructure)
 {
struct Table      filteredTable;
struct Table      fullTable;
size_t            filteredRowIndex;
size_t            fullRowIndex;
struct TokenList *nextNode;

if (tableStructure == NULL)
    return;
filteredTable = SQLloadTable(list, tableStructure);
nextNode      = list->next;
list->next    = NULL;
fullTable     = SQLloadTable(list, tableStructure);
list->next    = nextNode;
fullRowIndex  = 0;
for (filteredRowIndex = 0 ; filteredRowIndex < filteredTable.rowCount ; ++filteredRowIndex)
{
    // fullTable.rows[fullRowIndex++] =
}
}
```

and my linked list struct is  :

```
union Value
  {
   int integer;
   float number;
   char *string;
Bool boolean;
};

struct Column
{
union Value value;
enum FieldType type;
int position;
};

struct Row
{
int index;
struct Column columns[128];
size_t columnCount;
};

struct Table
{
struct Row *rows;
size_t rowCount;
};
```

Comment: Where are `TokenList`, `TableStructureInfo` etc. defined. What is the `SQLloadTable()` for?

Comment: Would you provide a reproducible example clearly stating the expected and the actual outputs.